# How can I update my xamarin android project with the latest NuGet packages support libraries?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using vs 2013 and xamarin version 4.7, for about 2 months I have been trying to install packages Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat
 and Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 and some other packages but I always receive the same error that says :

> "Could not install package 'package Name'. You are trying to install
>   this package into a project that targets 'mono.Android,Version=v5.0',
>   but the package does not contain any assembly references or content
>   files that are compatible with that framework. For more information,
>   contact the package author"

I've updated my xamarin android component to the last version, research this site, other site and test install packages by other android api version but my problem does not solve.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Vivien is correct, but after you change target API level, you probably will need to unload/reload the project in solution explorer, or restart VS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sahar,

If you are not compiling your application using Android version `7.0 (API Level 24 - Nougat)`, you can't install the latest support libraries `24.2.1` and above. The latest contains assemblies only compatible with `MonoAndroid70`, hence the error message.

As I see in the error message you are compiling using Android version `5.0 (API Level 22 - Lollipop)`, meaning the highest version of the support libraries you can install is `23.4.0.1`. That version contains assemblies compatible with `MonoAndroid403`.

If you are not ready to move to Nougat, it's ok not to have the latest version of the support libraries.

Comment: Thank you for help me and your answer. How can I update android version to 7.0? Did you mean in android SDK manager? and install packages API 24?

Comment: In your Android project properties, `Application tab`, change `Compile using Android version` to Android 7.0 (Nougat). And yes you'll have to get the tools for API 24 in the SDK Manager. Before doing that I advise you to do you research and check what it implies to move to Nougat.

Comment: @SaharSarikhani did I answer your question? If so don't forget to mark it as answered.

Comment: Yes I try to install API 24 android 7.0 but still have not find this API version in net! and in SDk manager option for API 24 does not exit!

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Visual Studio 2017 on Windows, try these two steps:

**Step One:**

Make sure you're running the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 or higher. Then, go to QuickSearch (Control-Q) and look for "Xamarin Android". Select "Xamarin - Android Settings".

[image]

Scroll down and check the box for **"Auto Install Android SDKs"**.

[image]

**Step Two:**

In your Android project, get Properties, then open the **Application** tab. Next to **Compile using Android version: (Target Framework)**, select the latest SDK.

[image]

Then, under the **Android Manifest** tab, select **Target Android version** and select **Use Compile using SDK version**. You can still support earlier versions of Android - just select what you want, within reason, from the **Minimum Android version** dropdown. Be careful here - supporting super early versions of Android is likely fraught with peril.

[image]

Once you've taken care of these steps, you should be able to install the latest Android support libraries. I imagine there are similar steps to VS Mac, but I haven't checked.

Good luck!